# A column that looks and behaves like a date in the contingency table cannot be sorted properly

Tags: sql-server, excel, pivot-table

I pulled up an Excel pivot table linked to the database. I have a column in it that has a date in the format dd.mm.yyyy. The column is recognized as a date, switching between short date, long date and time works for it. It also displays the ordering from oldest to newest, rather than A to Z. But when I want to sort this column, it doesn't sort properly. For example, when I sort it from newest date to oldest, the dates come up in the following order:

```
30.01.2023
25.05.2022
01.09.2022
01.09.2022
12.12.2022
12.12.2022
30.01.2023
30.01.2023
02.11.2021
05.01.2022
25.05.2022
27.06.2022
18.10.2022
```

which don't make sense. Do you know where is the problem? I can upload a SQL query linked to this table if it helps. Thank you for any suggestions :-)

For example, I tried to make one more column from the problem column via

```
CONVERT(varchar, CAST(sd.posting_date as datetime), 104) AS "Invoice date"
```

However, that didn't help either. This column then could not be switched to the date in Excel

Comment: Is this about Excel or SQL Server? It's unclear where you are having the problem. It *sounds* like you aren't storing your date as a `date`; a fatal and fundamental flaw.

Comment: The problem is probably related to Excel. There should be no problem with the date in the database. It is stored in it as a date in the format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.nnn". Even in Excel, the column is identified as a date. However, the sorting simply does not work as it should

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `ORDER BY`  to get them sorted as follows :

In `order by` the datatype should datetime

```
select CONVERT(varchar, CAST(sd.posting_date as datetime), 104) AS "Invoice date"
from mytable sd
order by convert(datetime, sd.posting_date, 104) desc
```

Comment: Ok, I am gonna try that. Hope it'll fix my problem in Pivot Table :)